# Why am I not able to access global variables?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, global-variables

I am new both to coding and to Xcode and am working on my first iOS app - so please forgive me if the answer to my question is obvious to experienced developers.

My app works but the design looks very "old fashioned" due to the buttons I have on each View Controller. I would prefer to use a more modern navigation system using Navigation Bars with Navigation buttons at the top of each screen. However, when I use this method of navigation the global variables entered on my first View Controller cannot be accessed on my final View Controller. I have double checked my Swift code files for each View Controller which, as explained, works fine if I have UIButtons instead of the Navbar.

The only difference I can see is that the Xcode 11 Navbar system uses the "Show" (Push) method of segues between View Controllers whereas my storyboard buttons use modal presentation.

I would be grateful if someone can steer me in the right direction - thanks!

The code showing the global variables from the first view controller is:

\\

```
import UIKit

var name = ""
var lastname = ""
var address = ""
var city = ""
var zip = ""
var email = ""
var phone = ""
var dateofbirth = ""

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var outlet: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet6: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet8: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outlet7: UITextField!
    

    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
    
    
    
    // Code for First Name
    
    
    if (outlet.text != "")
    
    {
        name = outlet.text!
    }
        
        
    // Code for Last Name
    if (outlet2.text != "")
     
    {
    lastname = outlet2.text!
    }
    
    // Code for Address
    if (outlet3.text != "")
         
    {
    address = outlet3.text!
    }
        
    // Code for city
    if (outlet4.text != "")
                    
    {
    city = outlet4.text!
    }
        
    // Code for Zip
    if (outlet5.text != "")
                               
    {
    zip = outlet5.text!
    }
        
    // Code for Email
    if (outlet6.text != "")
                                   
    {
    email = outlet6.text!
    }
        
    // Code for Phone
    if (outlet7.text != "")
                                       
    {
    phone = outlet7.text!
    }
    
    // Code for Date of Birth
    if (outlet8.text != "")
                                           
    {
    dateofbirth = outlet8.text!
    }
    
    // Dismissal of Keyboard
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event:      UIEvent?) {
        view.endEditing(true)
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        
    
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

}
}

```
\\\\
```

The code for the final View Controller is:

```
\\\\
import UIKit


class ReportViewController: UIViewController {

//Client ID Label Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label2: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label3: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label5: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label6: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label7: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var Label8: UILabel!

// Return function 
@IBAction func unwindToReportVC (_sender:UIStoryboardSegue){
   
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool){

    // Client ID Labels text using declared global variables

    Label.text = name
    Label2.text = lastname
    Label3.text = address
    Label4.text = city
    Label5.text = zip
    Label6.text = email
    Label7.text = phone
    Label8.text = dateofbirth
```

}
}

Comment: It would be a good first step to an answer if you provide the code of your controllers.

Comment: Add the relevant code.

Comment: "global variables entered on my first View Controller". In fact they are not global variables, just local to the view controller. You can create true global (do it in a singleton) and use them in all VC. Or you can pass data between VC if you segue, or use delegation (well adapted if you have a navigation bar) so that next or final VC can access data from first VC.

Comment: Sorry, because I am new to programming I now realise my terminology was incorrect! I did add the 'variables' outside the first view controller class i.e between 'Import UI Kit' and the ViewController class. I have now added the code for the two view controllers to my question. This code works well if I use storyboard 'Submit' Buttons but will not work with Nav Bar buttons. Just to clarify - the Nav bar buttons are linked to the Swift file IBAction function as well as the 'Show' segues.